# How to use TableCellEditor to edit checkbox

Tags: checkbox, tablecelleditor

I created an application that retrieves datas from a Mysql database and displays them in a JTable. Then I added checkboxes in the 1st column and I am able to display them with TableCellRendere. But when I try to check them , the checkboxes are not checked. In fact, I read how to use properly a TableCellEditor in this link, but I didn't understand well:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html

Then I got this code but I don't know what to add in the method `public Component getTableCellEditorComponent()`.

Here is the code which I need to complete:

```
public class CheckBoxCellEditor  extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor { 

protected JCheckBox checkBox;

    public CheckBoxCellEditor() {
        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);           
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
            JTable table, 
            Object value, 
            boolean isSelected, 
            int row, 
            int column) {

       // What should I add here and can you explain me 

        return checkBox;
    }
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return Boolean.valueOf(checkBox.isSelected());
    }
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue:

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSelectionDemoProject/src/components/TableSelectionDemo.java][1]

Thanks